# IO exception is generated when i try to copy from 1 file to other file

Tags: c#, winforms

I create an empty file and try to copy the contents from an existing to the newly created file. When i do that i am getting an IOexception

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String test = textBox1.Text.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter the filename");

        }
        else
        {
            StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(test);
            MessageBox.Show(test + " Has been created");
        }
    }
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String test = textBox1.Text.ToString();

        try
        {
            File.Copy(@"D:\\Study this.txt", test);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("IO error occured");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to close the `Stream` so in the `else` statement add File.Close(); that will release the newly created file.  That section of the code will now look like this:

```
StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(test);
File.Close();
MessageBox.Show(test + " Has been created");
```

Answer (score 1):

replace line `StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(test);` with below

```
using (File.Create(test)) ;
```

or with

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(test)){}
```

reason for above change is you need to propery close the opend stream object before the copy.

`using` block will handle that for you.

Comment: Agreed, exactly what I was going to post.